# Calculate different percentages in one function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

I have a table of values and their percentages like so:

```
astroid a  nickel: 20%   water: 25%  cobalt: 55%
astroid b  nickel: 30%   water: 35%  cobalt: 45%
astroid c  nickel: 240%  water: 45%  cobalt: 65%
```

I have to total mass of the asteroid so I need to calculate for every asteroid the amount of nickel, water etc

The mass of the asteroid is a prop I pass down from my parent component where I fetch the data, and I passed that to my child component.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Asteroids extends Component {
  render() {
    let t = 1;
    t = t + Math.round(Math.log(this.props.item.mass));
    console.log(t, "test");

    
    function percentage(num, per) {
      return (num / 100) * per;
    }

    console.log(percentage(this.props.item.mass, 0.12));

    return (
      <div className="as">
        <ul className="dashed">
          <li> Type: {this.props.item.type}</li>
          <li> Name: {this.props.item.name}</li>
          <li> days left until mining</li>
          <li> Mass: {this.props.item.mass}</li>
          <li> mining days: {t}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I want to make a function that calculates each percentage of water nickel etc per asteroid.

How do I go about it?

Comment: well you already wrote it, `function percentage...`, just make sure that your 2nd argument is a value between 1 and 100, ex. `percentage(this.props.item.mass, 12)`

Comment: in what i wrote i only calculate one percentage, but every asteriod is made of out nickel water etc so i want to calculate how much water it has and how much iron. An the percentages per asteroid are different

Comment: how does your asteroid object look like?

Comment: just with name: "", type: "", mass: 30000 , the percentages i wrote in the table are not part of the asteroid object, those where just the percentages given to calculate water etc of each asteroid

Answer (score 0):

You need to define types as an object, I hope that you'll understand the calc function.

```js
// you need to define types as an object
const types = {
  a : { nickel: 20,   water: 25,  cobalt: 55 },
  b : { nickel: 30,   water: 35,  cobalt: 45 },
  c : { nickel: 240,  water: 45,  cobalt: 65 }
}

// your asteroid object
const asteroid = { name: "sofia", type: "c", mass: 60000 }

function calcAmount(ast){
  const calcPerc = (per, mass) => (mass / 100) * per;
  const typeObj = types[ast.type];
  const returnObj = {}
  for(let key in typeObj){
    returnObj[key] = calcPerc(typeObj[key], ast.mass)
  }
  return returnObj
}

// now you can extract the amount of minerals
console.log(calcAmount(asteroid))
```

Comment: no more like asteroid ={ name: "sofia", type: "c", mass: 60000}  and the percentages of nickel etc aren't part of the object but just given to me to calculate the percentage of water etc per asteroid

Comment: type c in that case means `nickel: 240%  water: 45%  cobalt: 65%` ?

Comment: in means that asteroid with the type c has to be calculated with these percentages so let say the name is sofia the type is c, so now i need to calculate the amount of nickel with the percentage given 240% and the amount of water with the percentage give 45 % etc because for every asteroid the percentage of water etc is different